# Display RDL Report on Angular Application

Tags: angular, reporting-services, report, rdl

So, I have to display a SSRS/RDL report on a ReportViewer using an Angular 11 application, this report will be sent as a response from the backend after sending all the required parameters, the format of this response will be a FileStream.

All the plugins that I have found either use a SSRS server (which we don't have) or a file path in order to display the report.

Is it possible to get a file path from this stream that I will get from the response or any way to display this stream into an HTML5 iframe?

Thanks in advance